# Excel VBA Macro to get the substring of text before semicolon

Tags: vba, excel, split, substring

I have working code here.

In section (3) it grabs values from a cell under a specific header and prints them to a masterfile. These values typically look like

**TL-18273982; 10MM**

**TL-288762; 76DK**

**CT-576**

**N/A**

I would like to grab just the information that is before the first semicolon. Not all the cells have a semi colon in them so it would probably need an if statement along the lines of if ; then print everything in front of it.

I have been trying to utilize a split function to do this but I am not very experienced with VBA so I am having some trouble. Any suggestions?

```
Option Explicit

Sub LoopThroughDirectory()

    Const ROW_HEADER As Long = 10

    Dim objFSO As Object
    Dim objFolder As Object
    Dim objFile As Object
    Dim MyFolder As String
    Dim StartSht As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet
    Dim WB As Workbook
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim LastRow As Integer, erow As Integer
    Dim Height As Integer
    Dim RowLast As Long
    Dim f As String
    Dim dict As Object
    Dim hc As Range, hc1 As Range, hc2 As Range, hc3 As Range, d As Range

    Set StartSht = Workbooks("masterfile.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1")

    'turn screen updating off - makes program faster
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'location of the folder in which the desired TDS files are
    MyFolder = "C:\Users\trembos\Documents\TDS\progress\"

    'find the headers on the sheet
    Set hc1 = HeaderCell(StartSht.Range("B1"), "HOLDER")
    Set hc2 = HeaderCell(StartSht.Range("C1"), "CUTTING TOOL")

    'create an instance of the FileSystemObject
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    'get the folder object
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(MyFolder)
    i = 2


    'loop through directory file and print names
'(1)
    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
        If LCase(Right(objFile.Name, 3)) = "xls" Or LCase(Left(Right(objFile.Name, 4), 3)) = "xls" Then
'(2)

            'Open folder and file name, do not update links
            Set WB = Workbooks.Open(fileName:=MyFolder & objFile.Name, UpdateLinks:=0)
            Set ws = WB.ActiveSheet
'(3)
                'find CUTTING TOOL on the source sheet
                Set hc = HeaderCell(ws.Cells(ROW_HEADER, 1), "CUTTING TOOL")
                If Not hc Is Nothing Then

                    Set dict = GetValues(hc.Offset(1, 0))
                    If dict.count > 0 Then
                        Set d = StartSht.Cells(Rows.count, hc2.Column).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                        'add the values to the masterfile, column 3
                        d.Resize(dict.count, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(dict.items)
                    End If
                Else
                    'header not found on source worksheet
                End If
'(4)
                'find HOLDER on the source sheet
                Set hc3 = HeaderCell(ws.Cells(ROW_HEADER, 1), "HOLDER")
                If Not hc3 Is Nothing Then

                    Set dict = GetValues(hc3.Offset(1, 0))
                    If dict.count > 0 Then
                        Set d = StartSht.Cells(Rows.count, hc1.Column).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                        'add the values to the master list, column 2
                        d.Resize(dict.count, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(dict.items)
                    End If
                Else
                    'header not found on source worksheet
                End If
'(5)
            With WB
               'print TDS information
                For Each ws In .Worksheets
                        'print the file name to Column 1
                        StartSht.Cells(i, 1) = objFile.Name
                        'print TDS name from J1 cell to Column 4
                        With ws
                            .Range("J1").Copy StartSht.Cells(i, 4)
                        End With
                        i = GetLastRowInSheet(StartSht) + 1
                'move to next file
                Next ws
'(6)
                'close, do not save any changes to the opened files
                .Close SaveChanges:=False
            End With
        End If
    'move to next file
    Next objFile
    'turn screen updating back on
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1
'(7)
End Sub

'(8)
'get all unique column values starting at cell c
Function GetValues(ch As Range) As Object
    Dim dict As Object, rng As Range, c As Range, v
    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    For Each c In ch.Parent.Range(ch, ch.Parent.Cells(Rows.count, ch.Column).End(xlUp)).Cells
        v = Trim(c.Value)
        If Len(v) > 0 And Not dict.exists(v) Then
            dict.Add c.Address, v
        End If
    Next c
    Set GetValues = dict
End Function

'(9)
'find a header on a row: returns Nothing if not found
Function HeaderCell(rng As Range, sHeader As String) As Range
    Dim rv As Range, c As Range
    For Each c In rng.Parent.Range(rng, rng.Parent.Cells(rng.Row, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft)).Cells
        If Trim(c.Value) = sHeader Then
            Set rv = c
            Exit For
        End If
    Next c
    Set HeaderCell = rv
End Function

'(10)
Function GetLastRowInColumn(theWorksheet As Worksheet, col As String)
    With theWorksheet
        GetLastRowInColumn = .Range(col & .Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
    End With
End Function

'(11)
Function GetLastRowInSheet(theWorksheet As Worksheet)
Dim ret
    With theWorksheet
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
            ret = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                          After:=.Range("A1"), _
                          Lookat:=xlPart, _
                          LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                          SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                          SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                          MatchCase:=False).Row
        Else
            ret = 1
        End If
    End With
    GetLastRowInSheet = ret
End Function
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you one use `Split` function, you will love it -> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x627e5f%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Look for this example:

```
Sub TestSplit()

Dim String1 As String
Dim Arr1 As Variant

String1 = "TL-18273982; 10MM"
Arr1 = Split(String1, ";")

Debug.Print "TEST1: String1=" & String1
Debug.Print "TEST1: Arr1(0)=" & Arr1(0)
Debug.Print "TEST1: Arr1(1)=" & Arr1(1)

String1 = "CT-576"
Arr1 = Split(String1, ";")
Debug.Print "TEST2: String1=" & String1
Debug.Print "TEST2: Arr1(0)=" & Arr1(0)

String1 = "N/A"
Arr1 = Split(String1, ";")
Debug.Print "TEST3: String1=" & String1
Debug.Print "TEST3: Arr1(0)=" & Arr1(0)

End Sub
```

Results:

```
TEST1: String1=TL-18273982; 10MM
TEST1: Arr1(0)=TL-18273982
TEST1: Arr1(1)= 10MM
TEST2: String1=CT-576
TEST2: Arr1(0)=CT-576
TEST3: String1=N/A
TEST3: Arr1(0)=N/A
```

Edit:
Maybe simple modification `GetValues` will resolve problem?

Change function call to:

`Set dict = GetValues(hc.Offset(1, 0), "SplitMe")`

And change function like this:

```
'(8)
'get all unique column values starting at cell c
Function GetValues(ch As Range, Optional vSplit As Variant) As Object
    Dim dict As Object, rng As Range, c As Range, v
    Dim spl As Variant
    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    For Each c In ch.Parent.Range(ch, ch.Parent.Cells(Rows.Count, ch.Column).End(xlUp)).Cells
        v = Trim(c.Value)
        If Len(v) > 0 And Not dict.exists(v) Then

            If Not IsMissing(vSplit) Then
            spl = Split(v, ";")
            v = spl(0)
            End If

            dict.Add c.Address, v
        End If
    Next c
    Set GetValues = dict
End Function
```

Comment: That's great @Dawid . However the TL-... and CT-... etc that I have, there can be up to 50 cells full of that info per file so I cannot type each one out. Do you know how I could set String1 equal to whatever value the current cell has based on my code in section (3)?

Comment: This works perfectly. Thank you so much. One more quick question, if I wanted to make it so it splits with semicolons as well as commas, where would I add the , ? I tried an (v, ";" & ",") and adding another line spl = Split(v, ",") and both of those undid taking out the info after the ;. Would it need its own If statement? @Dawid

Comment: Never mind I got it to work. I just needed to copy and Paste from If Not IsMissing to the closest End If and change the semicolon to a comma. Thank you!

Comment: if you want split with multiple delimiters read this -> http://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/1480/How-to-Split-a-String-with-Multiple-Delimiters-in-VBA.html

Comment: Many thanks, friendly and simple --> My case only using the split option was more than enough, no need of Trim the value: "Split(Me.SampleInfo1.Value, "-")(1)"

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

```
Public Function PreSemicolon(sIN As String) As String
   If InStr(sIN, ";") = 0 Then
      PreSemicolon = ""
      Exit Function
   Else
      PreSemicolon = Split(sIN, ";")(0)
   End If
End Function
```

Comment: I will try this! Quick question. Do you know how I utilize the function in section (3) to run the function on the current cell? I am having trouble figuring out how to tie them together @Gary'sStudent

Answer (score 1):

The following VBA code snippet demonstrates the possible solution assuming the text is entered in "A1" cell (*Note*: it does not need Split() Function):

```
Sub GetSubstringDemo()
Dim position As Integer
Dim substring As String
position = InStr(Cells(1, 1), ";")
If (position > 0) Then
    substring = Left(Cells(1, 1), position - 1)
    'or use the following one to exclude "["
    'substring = Replace(Left(Cells(1, 1), position - 1), "[", "")
     Debug.Print substring
End If
End Sub
```

The same Sub can be extended to loop through the range of cells (e.g. A1 to A10):

```
Sub GetSubstringDemo()
    Dim position As Integer
    Dim substring As String
    For i = 1 To 10
        position = InStr(Cells(i, 1), ";")
        If (position > 0) Then
            substring = Replace(Left(Cells(i, 1), position - 1), "[", "")
            Debug.Print substring
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Hope this may help.

PS. Pertinent to you additional question in comments: business logic is a bit unclear, but following that sample code, it could be modified as :

```
Set dict = GetValues(hc.Offset(1, 0))
If dict.count > 0 Then
    Set d = StartSht.Cells(Rows.count, hc2.Column).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    position = InStr(d.Value, ";")
    substring = Replace(Left(d.Value, position - 1), ";", "")     
    d.Resize(dict.count, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(dict.items)
End If
```

Best Regards,

Comment: This is definitely helpful. Do you know how I might integrate this with my code in section 3? I am having trouble getting them to mesh well... I have this so far which I'm sure is very wrong. Also sorry for the confusion, the [] ws just supposed to designate a cell, it is not actually present. I'll edit that


`If dict.count > 0 Then
    Set d = StartSht.Cells(Rows.count, hc2.Column).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

    If (position > 0) Then
        substring = Replace(Left(Cells(1, 1), position - 1), ";", "")
    End If
    d.Resize(dict.count, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(dict.items)
End If`

Comment: Sorry it's hard to read code in comments. Here is a link to view it http://pastie.org/10231349. @AlexBell

Comment: I have extended my answer. Please check it accepted, and should you have more questions, please post them separately. Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that.I'm not sure about your variables, you might have to adapt them.

You can use instr to locate a character within the string (returning the position of '[' for example). You can then use mid to extract a substing, using the positions of ']' and '['.

```
openPos = instr (hc , "[") closePos = instr (hc , ";")

   if closePos = 0 then
   closePos = instr (hc , "]")
   end if 

dict = mid (hc , openPos+1, closePos - openPos - 1)
```